# _app.js Custom APP file does not work on NEXT JS 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to add a custom APP File on NEXT JS 13, in the documentation:

Next.js uses the App component to initialize pages. You can override it and control the page initialization and:

Persist layouts between page changes
Keeping state when navigating pages
Inject additional data into pages
Add global CSS
To override the default App, create the file ./pages/_app.js as shown below:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

I add the file, and the code but it does not work.

I am using the new APP Folder to make the routes. So I asume there is another way to make a custom APP file using the APP folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These `_document.jsx` and `_app.jsx` files aren't supported in the app directory.

[Here is the official migration documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-_documentjs-and-_appjs)

Comment: What's the new way of doing this?

Comment: From the docs: "If you have an existing _app or _document file, you can copy the contents (e.g. global styles) to the root layout (app/layout.tsx)."

Answer (score 0):

import your global css stuff (with any name you want) inside app/layout.tsx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).